# ReactJS states get reset

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following firebase database:

[image]

I want a react script that goes through the database and characterizes the data by position. Here's my attempt.

I created these following states:

```
    allExperts: [
      [] // holds arrays of expert records
    ],


    feat_experts: [
        [] // stores arrays of featured experts
    ],

    new_experts: [
        [] // stores arrays of new experts
    ]
};
```

Then I created this following method that populates allExperts state:

```
loadAllExperts(){
        var thisApp = this;
        // All Experts
        const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('experts');
        rootRef.once('value', snap => {
            var allExperts = [];
            snap.forEach(function(child){
                var queueExpert = [];
                child.forEach(function(g_child){
                    queueExpert.push(g_child.val());

                });
                allExperts.push(queueExpert);
            });
            thisApp.setState({
                allExperts: allExperts
            });
            console.log(this.state.allExperts);

        });
        this.refineFeatured();
    }
```

I assume that this would populate allExperts with whatever it gets from the database. The console.log() method prints the array just how I want it to.

Now I wanted to refine the allExperts state so that I only get featured experts. I do so by following method:

```
refineFeatured(){
        var allExperts = this.state.allExperts;
        console.log(allExperts);

        var allFeatExperts = [];
        var row = this.state.allExperts.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < row; i++){
            if(allExperts[i][5] === "featured"){
                allFeatExperts.push(allExperts[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            feat_experts: allFeatExperts
        });
    }
```

The console.log() method in that prints an empty array, so it did not populate allExperts in loadAllExperts() correctly.

Here's the entire code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import './Tab.css';
import { Tabs, Tab, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

class App extends Component {


    constructor(props) {

        super(props);
        this.state = {
            key: 1,

            /*
            *
            * allExperts: [
            *
            *   [email,message,name,occupation,phone,position],
            *   [...]
            *
            * ]
            *
            *
            * */
            allExperts: [
              []
            ],


            feat_experts: [
                []
            ],

            new_experts: [
                []
            ],

            pop_experts: [
                []
            ]
        };

        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
        this.loadAllExperts = this.loadAllExperts.bind(this);
        this.refineNew = this.refineNew.bind(this);

        this.loadAllExperts();

    }

    handleSelect(key) {
        this.setState({key});
    }


    loadAllExperts(){
        var thisApp = this;
        // All Experts
        const rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('experts');
        rootRef.once('value', snap => {
            var allExperts = [];
            snap.forEach(function(child){
                var queueExpert = [];
                child.forEach(function(g_child){
                    queueExpert.push(g_child.val());

                });
                allExperts.push(queueExpert);
            });
            thisApp.setState({
                allExperts: allExperts
            });
        });
        this.refineFeatured();
    }

    refineFeatured(){
        var allExperts = this.state.allExperts;
        console.log(allExperts);

        var allFeatExperts = [];
        var row = this.state.allExperts.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < row; i++){
            if(allExperts[i][5] === "featured"){
                allFeatExperts.push(allExperts[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            feat_experts: allFeatExperts
        });
    }

    refineNew(){
        var allExperts = this.state.allExperts;
        var allNewExperts = [];
        var row = this.state.allExperts.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < row; i++){
            if(allExperts[i] === "new"){
                allNewExperts.push(allExperts[i]);
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            new_experts: allNewExperts
        });
    }



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Button onClick={this.loadAllExperts}>Load Experts</Button>
                <div className="container browseArea">
                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                        <div className="col-lg-12">
                            <Tabs activeKey={this.state.key} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="controlled-tab-example" onLoad={this.loadAllExperts}>
                                <Tab eventKey={1} title="Featured" className="tab-ind">
                                    { allFeatExperts.map(function(exp, index){
                                        return(
                                            <div key={index}>
                                                <div className="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div className="col-lg-2">
                                                        <div className="well">
                                                            <img className="img-responsive" alt="alt-message0"
                                                                 src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-7">
                                                        <div className="well">
                                                            {/*email,message,name,occupation,phone,position*/}
                                                            <strong>Get Top Tier PR Media Exposure of Your Company for
                                                                Free.</strong><br/>
                                                            <span className="text-muted">{ exp[2] } • Los Angeles and Ottawa Canada</span><br />
                                                            <span className="description">{ exp[1] }</span>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-3">
                                                        <span className="price">
                                                            <div className="input-group">
                                                              <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$5/min</span>
                                                                <input type="button" className="form-control btn-success" value="Request a call" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-lg-12">
                                                    <hr className="step-divider"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                    })

                                    }


                                </Tab>
                                <Tab eventKey={2} title="New" className="tab-ind" onClick={this.refineNew}>

                                    { allNewExperts.map(function(exp, index){
                                        return(
                                            <div key={index}>
                                                <div className="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div className="col-lg-2">
                                                        <div className="well">
                                                            <img className="img-responsive" alt="alt-message0"
                                                                 src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-7">
                                                        <div className="well">
                                                            {/*email,message,name,occupation,phone,position*/}
                                                            <strong>Get Top Tier PR Media Exposure of Your Company for
                                                                Free.</strong><br/>
                                                            <span className="text-muted">{ exp[2] } • Los Angeles and Ottawa Canada</span><br />
                                                            <span className="description">{ exp[1] }</span>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div className="col-lg-3">
                                                        <span className="price">
                                                            <div className="input-group">
                                                              <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$5/min</span>
                                                                <input type="button" className="form-control btn-success" value="Request a call" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div className="col-lg-12">
                                                    <hr className="step-divider"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        )
                                    })

                                    }
                                </Tab>
                                <Tab eventKey={3} title="Popular" className="tab-ind">
                                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                                        <div className="col-lg-2">
                                            <div className="well">
                                                <img className="img-responsive" alt="alt-messagex"
                                                     src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-7">
                                            <div className="well">
                                                <strong>Get Top Tier PR Media Exposure of Your Company for
                                                    Free.</strong><br/>
                                                <span className="text-muted">Ardian Salamunovlo • Los Angeles and Ottawa Canada</span><br />
                                                <span className="description">I will show you how to get you top-tier media exposure. Wether you want to be featured, in TechCrunch or Mashable, WSJ, or Forbes, Inc. or FastCompany I've done it dozens of times and I have the experience to...</span>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-3">
                                            <span className="price">
                                                <div className="input-group">
                                                  <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$5/min</span>
                                                <input type="button" className="form-control btn-success"
                                                       value="Request a call" placeholder="Username"
                                                       aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                                        <hr className="step-divider"/>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className="col-lg-12">
                                        <div className="col-lg-2">
                                            <div className="well">
                                                <img className="img-responsive" alt="alt-message4"
                                                     src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-7">
                                            <div className="well">
                                                <strong>Get Top Tier PR Media Exposure of Your Company for
                                                    Free.</strong><br/>
                                                <span className="text-muted">Ardian Salamunovlo • Los Angeles and Ottawa Canada</span><br />
                                                <span className="description">I will show you how to get you top-tier media exposure. Wether you want to be featured, in TechCrunch or Mashable, WSJ, or Forbes, Inc. or FastCompany I've done it dozens of times and I have the experience to...</span>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div className="col-lg-3">
                                            <span className="price">
                                                <div className="input-group">
                                                  <span className="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$5/min</span>
                                                <input type="button" className="form-control btn-success"
                                                       value="Request a call" placeholder="Username"
                                                       aria-describedby="basic-addon1"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Tab>
                            </Tabs>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

The code in `render()` method might not make sense since it I am still debugging.

Also, I need to know the suitable place to call `refineFeatured()` and `refineNew()` method, I cannot call them in `constructor()` method as the components aren't initialized yet at that point.

For some reason, when I call them in `componenetDidMount()` method, they don't seem to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `setState()` does not guarantee that you state is updated immdiatelety, see the react docs:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. [1](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

This means your are still accessing the old state which is an empty array. You can solve this by passing the allExperts array to your refineFeatured function, instead of passing it via `this.state`.